# Return ID on INSERT?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

I have an INSERT query and I want the DB to return the ID of the row I just inserted.

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO MagicBoxes (OwnerID, Key, Name, Permissions, Active, LastUpdated) VALUES (@OwnerID, @BoxKey, @BoxName, 0, 1, @Date) SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerID", OwnerID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoxKey", BoxKey);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoxName", BoxName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I currently have this, I'm not sure what I need to do next...

Comment: Can't get your question, do you want the seed value of the row just inserted?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You just need to add @ID to the params collection and then retrieve it like this,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Now just read the value of: cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value
```

Or, if you prefer this syntax:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: `Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Data.ParameterDirection' to 'string'`

Comment: @Danpe = apologies, corrected above - I always find added output parameters a bit more clunky than it needs to be

Comment: I can't make this work, after executing the command the parameter is null.  Another answer on here uses ExecuteScalar and seems to produce the right value.

Answer (score 30):

Since SQL Server 2008 there was an [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) added to the syntax of TSQL. This allows you to have the data which is affected by the DML query added to the Tabular Data Stream.

Although querying SCOPE_IDENTITY() after a query returns the correct information it forces SQL Server to execute 2 queries where the output clause limits this to one query.

Knowing this, the query being executed can be altered as follows (Assuming `[Id]` is the name of the identity):

```
INSERT INTO MagicBoxes (OwnerID, [Key], Name, [Permissions], Active, LastUpdated) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (@OwnerID, @BoxKey, @BoxName, 0, 1, @Date)
```

Another issue is not disposing of the `SqlCommand`. Most of the `Sql...` objects in ADO.net implement `IDisposable` and should be disposed of properly.

Bringing everything together I would implement this piece of code as follows:

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                INSERT INTO MagicBoxes (OwnerID, [Key], Name, [Permissions], Active, LastUpdated) 
                OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
                VALUES (@OwnerID, @BoxKey, @BoxName, 0, 1, @Date) ", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@OwnerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OwnerID,
                    new SqlParameter("@BoxKey", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BoxKey, 
                    new SqlParameter("@BoxName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BoxName, 
                    new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now 
                });

            conn.Open();

            var id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 24):

You have two options; you could declare an `Output` parameter called `@ID`; or - you could change the end to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and just use:

```
int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I prefer the formal parameter approach, but `ExecuteScalar` works well.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your parameters

```
SqlParameter IDParameter = new SqlParameter("@ID",SqlDbType.Int);
IDParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(IDParameter);
```

After executing you can retrieve the id

```
int id = (int)IDParameter.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the store procedure. Pass values to the store procedure to get the values inserted and from the SP return the last seed value inserted using `SCOPE_IDENTITY().` Hope this help.

Comment: having a stored procedure wouldn't change anything; this is about the argument/result passing, which would be identical

Comment: Yeah you are right, I meant to say that call SP and from SP return the last seed value after insertion.