# Return @@IDENTITY upon INSERT to use as variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, scope-identity

I have a function which I want to perform an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` depending on whether the `ProfileID` found in the the imported `.csv` file is set to a current id or if it is a new one (if it's new, then it's marked as "New," "New1," "New2," etc. in the `ProfileId` column of the file).

Unfortunately, during the save process, there are a few functions that are called that require the use of the `ProfileID`. But if an `INSERT` is being performed, then the `ProfileID` is not known when these functions are called.

I have set up the `INSERT` query to return the `ProfileID` after inserting a new row using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but I am not sure how to take this result and place it in a variable. Is there a way to do this?

This is the entire save function code:

```
private void SaveProfile(string[] curProfile)
{  
    string profId = GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId).ToLower();

    string query ="";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        try
        {
            if (profId.Contains("new")) 
            {
                string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ProductProfile (Name, Description, SpeciesLink, LineDraw, LineDrawThumbnail, ProfileThumbnail, ComponentThickness, ComponentWidth, FinishedThickness, FinishedWidth, ClassificationID, StockOrCust, ComponentFactor, Visibility, Notes, OrderBy) VALUES (@Name, @Description, @SpeciesLink, @LineDraw, @LineDrawThumbnail, @ProfileThumbnail, @ComponentThickness, @ComponentWidth, @FinishedThickness, @FinishedWidth, @ClassificationID, @StockOrCust, @ComponentFactor, @Visibility, @Notes, @OrderBy) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
                Response.Write("PERFORM INSERT<br />");
                query = insertQuery;
            }

            {
                string updateQuery = "UPDATE ProductProfile SET Name = @Name, Description = @Description, SpeciesLink = @SpeciesLink, LineDraw = @LineDraw, LineDrawThumbnail = @LineDrawThumbnail, ProfileThumbnail = @ProfileThumbnail, ComponentThickness = @ComponentThickness, ComponentWidth = @ComponentWidth, FinishedThickness = @FinishedThickness, FinishedWidth = @FinishedWidth, ClassificationID = @ClassificationID, StockOrCust = @StockOrCust, ComponentFactor = @ComponentFactor, Visibility = @Visibility, Notes = @Notes, OrderBy = @OrderBy WHERE ProfileID = @profid";
                Response.Write("PERFORM UPDATE<br />");
                query = updateQuery;
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profid", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Name).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Description).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpeciesLink", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.SpeciesLink).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Linedraw", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDraw).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineDrawThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDrawThumbnail).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileThumbnail).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentThickness).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentWidth).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedThickness).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedWidth).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassificationID", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ClassificationID).Trim());

            string stockCust = GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.StockOrCust).ToLower();

            switch (stockCust)
            {
                case "stock":
                    stockCust = "0";
                    break;
                case "custom":
                    stockCust = "1";
                    break;
                case "discontinued":
                    stockCust = "2";
                    break;
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockOrCust", Convert.ToInt32(stockCust));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentFactor", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentFactor).Trim());

            string Visibility = GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Visibility).ToLower();

            switch (Visibility)
            {
                case "public":
                    Visibility = "0";
                    break;
                case "private":
                    Visibility = "1";
                    break;
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visibility", Convert.ToInt32(Visibility));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Notes).Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.OrderBy).Trim());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cn.Close();

            // this is the portion of the function that makes the call to other functions to complete the save process
            int profileID = Convert.ToInt32(GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId));
            SaveArtchStyle(profileID, curProfile);
            SaveAssignedItems(profileID, curProfile);
            //update dimensions
            //UpdateProductDimensions(profileID, GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedThickness).Trim(), GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedWidth).Trim());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "There was an error with the file." + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sara where are you using out Param in your cmd..? personally I would convert all that sql into a stored procedure..

Comment: Write a stored procedure called SaveProductProfile that calls "return scope_identity()" after the insert statement.  You can check for an existing record in the proc using if exists ( select * from ProductProfile where Id = @Id )

Comment: no need to check just declare an out variable for example @KeyId int OUTPUT then at the end of the Insert command do the following  SET `@KeyId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your C# code behind make sure you declare an output variable for example 
`qlParameter outputParam = new SqlParameter("@KeyId", SqlDbType.Int);
outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(outputParam);`
after your ExecuteNonQuery line you would want to assign or capture the output variable from the insert like this 
`outputId = (int)outputParam.Value;`

Comment: Also note that your `if` block does not have an `else` after it so the next block (the `update`) is overwriting your `insert` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ExecuteScalar()` function this returns the scope identity or 0 when it has failed. Check the MSDN documentation and example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 Int32 newProdID = 0;
 string sql =
    "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
    + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... forgot about that, but looks like it could work too.  :)

Comment: This is the answer to the question. I would use the output clause instead of scope_identity() but technically it is correct.

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of using (in your opinion) the output clause because even when you are using the output clause you need to set the @ID = scope_identity().

Comment: You can use `insert into ProductProfile (Name) output inserted.ProductId values (@Name)` it will output the new identity value in a single statement instead of running 2 statements.

Comment: I tried this out and it ended up working perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sarah, you should be able to add and use something of the like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Now just read the value of: cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value
```

Just make sure you put the @ID parameter before the execute query command.  You could even assign it to a variable as such:

```
var insertValue = cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value
```

Referenced idea is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910385/return-id-on-insert).

**UPDATE:**  I forgot to add that, as part of your insert statement, you need to do the following:

```
 SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```