# Returning ID of new row when ID is uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have created a SQL Server table that uses `uniqueidentifier` as the primary key. I set the *Default Value or Binding* to `newid()`. (I would like to set the *Identity Specification* for this column, but that isn't supported for `uniqueidentifier` types.)

I'm then using ADO.NET to add a row to this table.

```
SqlComment command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] (Name) VALUES (@name); 
                                     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", Connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Joe Smoe");
Guid userId = (Guid)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

However, the last line fails because `ExecuteScaler()` returns `null`. It appears that, since a `uniqueidentifier` cannot be the table's *identity*, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `null` (as does `@@IDENTITY`).

Okay, so is there another way to retrieve the newly added ID using ADO.NET?

Comment: That's because SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last inserted IDENTITY value. Your table doesn't have an identity so NULL is the only thing that can be returned. One reason that guids have become so popular is because you can define it in your code and pass it to sql server. I sure hope if that is your primary key it is NOT the clustered index. You might also take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() is only used for Identity value, for guid values you would need to use the OUTPUT clause with a table variable.

```
DECLARE @NewGuid TABLE(NewValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

INSERT INTO [User] (Name)
OUTPUT inserted.pk_ColName INTO  @NewGuid(NewValue)
VALUES (@name); 

SELECT * FROM @NewGuid  --<-- here you will have the new GUID Value
```

C# code would look something like....

```
string cmd = "DECLARE @NewGuid TABLE(NewValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
                INSERT INTO [User] (Name)
                OUTPUT inserted.pk_ColName INTO  @NewGuid(NewValue)
                VALUES (@name); 
                SELECT @newID = NewValue FROM @NewGuid;"


SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Joe Smoe");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Guid userId = (Guid)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Personally I would put the whole thing in a stored procedure.

Comment: You don't have to add the output parameter if you use ExecuteScalar() if you are only outputting one value.

Answer (score 1):

Scope_Identity() focuses on an IDENTITY field, so it will never yield anything. You need to output from INSERTED instead. Even though this page is not focused on your particular problem, it should give you some clues:

[Return ID on INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910385/return-id-on-insert)

My normal direction is a stored procedure, but you can chain commands, as you have done. The stored procedure makes things a bit easier, as you can create an output parameter for the procedure, but outputting a value works fine.

EDITED to show specific example:

Assume the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
)
```

The following program will output the new GUID created from NewID():

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDB"].ToString();
        var cmdString = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) OUTPUT Inserted.Id VALUES ('Name')";

        var connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        var command = new SqlCommand(cmdString, connection);

        Guid outputValue;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            //Convert to Guid here instead
            Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Dispose();
        }

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Comment: I understand about OUTPUT parameters, but the suggestions at the page you linked would have the same problem I'm having now. I still need a way to obtain the new ID in order to assign it to the OUTPUT parameter. (Stored procedures aren't the best choice for what I'm doing.)

Comment: It does answer the question if you look at the answers. Editing to pull crap over so you can see what I am talking about.