# How to use last insert id pass to another table

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to use last insert id pass to another table

i have two table 1.product 2.stock i have enclosed with images below. 
[image]

[image]

stack table proid  is last insert id come from product table which should add on stock table but
i couldn't add please see the code i tried below

```
MySqlCommand cm1 = new MySqlCommand();
cm1.Connection = con;
cm1.CommandText = "insert into products(name,qty,price) values (@name,@qty,@price)";

cm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
cm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", textBox3.Text);
cm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBox4.Text);
con.Open();

// Return the id of the new record. Convert from Int64 to Int32 (int).
//   return Convert.ToInt32(cm1.Parameters["@newId"].Value);

MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand();
cm.Connection = con;
cm.CommandText = "insert into stock(caname,qty,price) values (@caname,@qty,@price)";
//cm.CommandText = "insert into products(name,qty,price) values (@caname,@qty,@price)";
//  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
// cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proid", id);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caname", textBox2.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", textBox3.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBox4.Text);

cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This sure does not look like C.  Did you mean C#?  Please tag properly.

Comment: This has already been answered, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910385/return-id-on-insert